# Way to deploy VS2010 WinForms application with SQL 2012 LocalDb with VS 2010 Installer

Tags: sql, installation, localdb

Is there a reference on creating a Visual Studio 2010 Installer project for a WinForms application that uses SQL 2012 LocalDb?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any good reference, but it is pretty easy. The ClickOnce packages are compatible between Visual Studio 2010 and 2012, so all you'd need to do is to install Visual Studio 2012 somewhere to get the LocalDB bootstrapper (free VS 2012 Express for Desktop) and copy `SqlLocalDB2012` folder from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages` (depending on your Windows installation the location could be slightly different, but should be easy to find).

Now the caveat is that to connect from .NET to LocalDB you need .NET 4.0.2 or later. I don't think there is a bootstrapper for .NET 4.0.2 anywhere. So you will either need to implement it yourself, or target .NET 4.5. You should be able to copy the .NET 4.5 bootstrapper from VS 2012 just like you can copy the LocalDB one.